# trying to make use of copy assignment operator

Tags: c++

[image]

```
Product& Product::operator=(const Product& src)
{
    if (this != &src) {
        strcpy(m_sku, src.m_sku);
        m_price = src.m_price;
        m_status = src.m_status;
        m_Cquantity = src.m_Cquantity;
        m_Nquantity = src.m_Nquantity;

        if (src.m_name != nullptr) {
            m_name = new char[strlen(src.m_name) + 1];
            strncpy(m_name, src.m_name, (strlen(src.m_name) + 1));
        }
        else {
            m_name = nullptr;
        }
    }
}

std::fstream& Product::load(std::fstream& file)
{
    char sku_[max_sku_length + 1];
    char name[max_name_length + 1];
    char unit[max_unit_length + 1];
    int  quantity, qtyNeeded;
    double price_;
    char taxed_;
    file.open(m_name, ios::in);
    file >> sku_;
    file >> name;
    file >> unit;
    file >> taxed_;
    file >> price_;
    file >> quantity;
    file >> qtyNeeded;

    *this = file;   // ERROR

    file.clear();
    file.close();    

    return file;
}
```

I am new to C++. I am working on one of my school projects. I need to create this function:

> • std::fstream& load(std::fstream& file)
>
> This modifier receives a reference to an fstream object and returns a reference to that fstream object. This function
>
> - extracts the fields for a single record from the fstream object
> - creates a temporary object from the extracted field data
> - copy assigns the temporary object to the current object.

I am not sure if I am doing it right. It gives me an error at

```
*this = file;
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `*this` is a `Product`, `file` is a `std::fstream`, how would you expect one to be able to be assigned to the other? (Ignoring the fact that streams can't be copied)  Read the data into your member variables, not newly declared ones.

Comment: So what is the possible way to do "copy assigns the temporary object to the current object."?

Comment: `Product temp; file >> temp.m_sku; ... *this = temp;`

Comment: @Azal Also want to point out that you should make sure to delete `m_name`'s memory before you assign to it again, after checking if it's not a `nullptr` first of course. Failing to do so results in a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks so very much :)

Comment: @Xenonic actually it is safe to delete a `nullptr`, the C++ language spec guarantees that doing so will be a harmless no-op.